# Bash: Revert nonexecutable files that have mistakenly been changed

Tags: bash, executable, file-extension

So in one of my directories I ran

```
    chmod -R ugo+rx
```

which turned every file in this directory (and all directories within) into files with executable permissions.

Now, I could either try to revert this by using

```
    chmod -$ ugo-x <a ton of non-executable file extensions>
```

or by removing executable permissions on everything that isn't an executable (Backup is not an option)

Any suggestions on the best way to go about this? This directory (external hard drive) contains lots of data and programs, but none of which are crucial to the function of the machine.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Undoing this operation is impossible without a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As l0b0 told you, it is impossible revert it without backup.

Some help could come from the `file` command, what can detect compiled executables, and scripts with shebang line.

For the rough idea, you can try:

```
find /mnt/hdd -type f -print | file -f -
```

or

```
find /mnt/hdd -type f -print | file -i -f -
```

and you will see what file=types are detected. If detected some executables, you can try leave those as is and remove the executable bit from others. The remaining files must do manually - cherry pick...

The above `file -f -` read filenames from the `stdin`. This functionality is on `FreeBSD` - i havent Linux. If your `file` command hasn't the `-f` switch, you can try (much slower)

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file
```

Answer (score 0):

The majority of files are supposed to be non-executable, so just start off with a

```
find dir -type f -exec chmod a-x {} \;
```

Then, you can search for files that should have +x. I wouldn't even bother with `file` since it differentiates between many different type of executable scripts, and we want all of them:

```
find dir -type f -exec grep -q -e '^.ELF' -e '^#!' \; -print -exec chmod a+x {} \;
```

This sets +x to on interpretted scripts in any language, plus elf binaries.

A more obscure version can be used to further reduce false positives, with diminishing returns:

```
find dir -type f -exec bash -c 'sed 1p "$1" | grep -q -e "^.ELF" -e "^#!"' -- {} \; -print -exec chmod a+x {} \;
```